# stm32l476 ADC not ready

Tags: stm32, keil

I am trying to bring up one of the ADC's on the STM32L476 Nucleo board. I think i have things configured ok, but i must be missing a step. I know this can be done use the HAL API and CubeMX, but i prefer register level access when bringing up a new board. Here is my code - i think it's commented to enough so it can be understood. I stripped out the rest of the code to keep it simple.

The problem i don't understand is that when the code starts the while loop - the ADC is not ready - that is the ADC1->ISR[0] is not set - and does not get set. I have confirmed the bits are set where i think they should be using keil.

Can anyone spot what is missing?

```
#include <stm32l4xx.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif

int main(void)
{

    uint32_t adcResult = 0;

    /* Configure the clocks - using MSI as SYSCLK @16MHz */
    RCC->CR             &=  0xFFFFFF07;     //Clear ~MSIRANGE bits and MSIRGSEL bit
    RCC->CR             |=  0x00000089;     //Set MSI to 16MHz and MSIRGSEL bit
    char *dataPtr = NULL;

    //init ADC1
    ADC1->CR     &= 0xDFFFFFFF;      //Take ADC out of deep power down - i break at this point to allow enough time - doesn't help
    ADC1->CR     |= 0x10000000;    //Enable ADC1 votage regulator
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= 0x00002001;    //Enable the ADC clock, and GPIOA clk
    GPIOA->ASCR  |= 0x00000001;    //Connect analog switch to GPIOA[0]
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x00000003;    //Set A0 for analog input mode
    ADC1->ISR    |= 0x00000001;    //Clear the ADRDY bit in the ADCx_ISR register by writing ‘1’.
    ADC1->SQR1   |= 0x00000040;    //Set for a sequence of 1 conversion on CH0


    while (1)
    {
            ADC1->CR |= 0x00000004;       //Convst
            while(!(ADC1->ISR & 0x4));
            adcResult = ADC1->DR;
            sprintf(dataPtr, "%d", adcResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still can't get this to work with the code above - not sure why, i have spun up the same setup using CubeMX - which works. I'm trying to understand the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this - finally. If anyone gets into the same place. I had set the SYSCLK as the ADC clock source, but this needs to be setup in RCC->CCIPR[29:28].

It's the little things...